# Check boxes and combined text output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, checkbox

I need help with code for a combined text box output.

[See this picture with the final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8orE8.jpg)

A. Input: The user should choose among different checkbox options.

B. Output: The selected text strings should go collectively to an updated text box. The textbox should update instantly as the checkboxes are selected, so you will se the final result directly.

C. Transfer: By clicking a button the content of the text box should copy to memory for later insertion in other software.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you show what you have tried so far. So So people can see where you are stuck and be able to help you. What you have is requirement not an OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='country']").change(function(){
        var checkedCountries = $("input[name='country']:checked");
        var countries = [];
        for(var i = 0; i<checkedCountries.length; i++) {
            countries.push(checkedCountries[i].value + ".");
        }
        $("#countryList").val(countries.join(" "));

    });

    $("#copyBtn").click(function() {
        var copyText = document.getElementById("countryList");
        copyText.select();
        document.execCommand("Copy");
        alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" name="country" value="America">America<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="country" value="Burma">Burma<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="country" value="China">China<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="country" value="Denmark">Denmark<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="country" value="England">England<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="country" value="France">France<br>
<textarea id="countryList"></textarea></br>

<input type="button" id="copyBtn" value="Copy Country List"/>
</body>
</html>
```

You can copy text to clipboard using pure javascript way as given in above snippet.

Comment: If you take a look at the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) for the exec command the copy function was added to safari on September 20th, 2016. This may be a bit recent unless you can assure users without at all outdated safari will be using your site.

Comment: The example by Nitin Kothwal works fine (for one parameter COUNTRY), but I have more than one parameter. How can I include these (CAPITAL, COLOR, NUMBER) in the textbox so that all parameters are included in the textbox instantly as the checkboxes are selected? If possible also include NUMBER (text input instead of checkbox). Source: [link](http://a-star.dk)

Answer (score 0):

A. Input

You'll want to write some code to listen to checkbox events, I recommend looking into javascript for this. Javascript is a programming language available in all major web browsers. (It's pretty much your only option).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics
If you're new to js try doing some google searches for things like "get event from checkbox change in js"

B. Output
When your code receives a checkbox event you'll want it to loop through the checkboxes, figure out which ones are checked, and then compose a string. The code can then insert that string into the text field.

You could also figure out which one changed, and decide how to change your existing text based on that, or remember the checkbox states for the checkboxes to generate your output. This would be faster but is probably over complicating things.

C. I assume you mean copy to clipboard... Take a look at this library! https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: Yes I want to copy the content of the textbox to the clipboard. I tried to use clipboardjs on my test page (www.a-star.dk) but not with succes. I'm not sure what I did wrong here, but when working it solves the issue.